# Validate form submission for an array file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery multiple file upload plugin from http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ . I want to validate the from submission. I want to make sure that the file field which is an array should not be empty I tried the below code but is not working.

```
function validateForm()
{

var x=document.forms["classifieds"]["file[]"].length;
if(x ==0)
{ 
  alert('Please select a file');
  return false;
}
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried using multiple file upload using plugin, however there is no proper docs any such pre-defined methods.  *But in your case instead of checking for **`0`**, try to check with **`undefined`**.*

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["classifieds"]["file[]"].length;
    if (x == undefined) {
        alert('Please select a file');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Following are the different conditions I performed with form submit:

1) Without uploading any file,

```
document.forms["classifieds"]["file[]"].length  //returns undefined
```

2) With some files

```
one file uploaded   // returns 2
two files  uploaded // returns 3
and so on
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/TvYN2/)

Hope you understood.